# VBA divide by a value then display value in relation to the divison

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure the cleanest way of showing, as an example, an initial value say `300` as `x` and a critical path say `1.5` as `y`. Both of these values can change, via input on the sheet.

Together with these values we have a resource of `a` and `b`. In this scenario `a` will fill `200` cells within a row and `b` will fill `100`.

As I alluded to before, `x` and `y` can change, say, if `y` is `2`, `a` fills `150` and `b` fills `150`. And if `y` is `1` then only `a` fills `300`.

Currently i'm using If statements, but I feel this is messy and could potentially lead to endless code in order to cover every possible outcome and I'm in need of a better solution.

Here is a simplistic example of what I'm currently achieving:

```
Private Sub Example()

    Dim ActiveWB As Worksheet
    Set ActiveWB = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim a, b, x, y As Double

    x = ActiveWB.Range("A1").Value
    y = ActiveWB.Range("A2").Value
    a = x / y
    b = x - a

        For Each cell In ActiveWB.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, a))

            If (cell.Column >= 0) And (cell.Column <> x) Then

                If (y = 1) And (a > 0) Then
                   cell.Value = "a"
                    a = a - 1

                ElseIf (y > 1) And (y < 2) And (a > 0) Then
                   cell.Value = "a"
                   a = a - 1
                   If (b > 0) Then
                        cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "b"
                        b = b - 1
                   End If

               ElseIf (y >= 2) And (y < 2.5) And (a > 0) Then
                   cell.Value = "a"
                   a = a - 1
                   If (b > 0) Then
                        cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "b"
                        b = b - 1
                   End If

                '..... and so on......

                End If

            End If

        Next cell

End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time. Y.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to accomplish T_T

Comment: @Chris Is it a problem with the description or the required solution?

Comment: Why are you testing the `y` value ?  It appears as though 'a' is default for every cell, and the first `b` cells in the second column get "b"

Comment: @YaMo Feel free to select K_B's answer as the correct answer. I answered earlier but K_B's answer is more useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First of all** declaring types should be done for each variable separately:

```
Dim a, b, x, y As Double
```

Becomes:

```
Dim a As Double, b As Double, x As Double, y As Double
```

Or (this is what I prefer):

```
Dim a As Double
Dim b As Double
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double
```

**Second**, if your a and b are only used for determining the range width, then they are preferably not of a floating point type. In stead use Integer (under 2^15) or Long:

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double
```

Then your value assignment to a and b cannot stay the way they are now, but should read something like:

```
a = Int(x / y)
b = Int(x - a)
```

Then I hope your x and y values are restricted to values > 0 and x > y in your sheet. If not then first test for that in your script...

**Now last** (**and your original question**), you can assign a value to a complete range of cells if you like:

```
If a > 0 Then Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, a)).Value = "a"
If b > 0 Then Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, b)).Value = "b"
```

I dont understand why you take of 1 from a and b, so if that really add something, please elaborate a bit more on the general logic...

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and explanation, I'm still very new to VBA. +1

Comment: @ K_B It's from the more complex logic original code. As the values loop through sections and values are placed within relation to these resources.

Comment: @Chris, please declare `Dim a, b, c as Integer` and look at the Type for each of those in your Locals watch window.  See also: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx , scroll down to Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement

Comment: +1, definitely a more useful answer. I'd also recommend renaming `ActiveWB` as it would be easy to mistakenly think it should be a workbook object, when actually it's a worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

I probably don't completely understand the complexity, but based upon what you shared you can replace your for loop with the following to achieve the same result:

```
ActiveWB.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, a)).Value = "a"
If b > 0 then
    ActiveWB.Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(4, b)).Value = "b"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this works well. I think my example was a tad too simplistic. But i am happy to accept this.

Comment: @YaMo consider the case when `b = 0`

Comment: @K_B I know, that could have been corrected too but I was just replicating his stated behavior. I decided not to point out other things I'd have suggested changing, unlike your answer.